# react-router parameterize redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble figuring out how to parameterize a route string for programmatically redirecting.

my setup in `/constants/routes.js`

```
export defaults {
  user_details: '/user/:id/details',
}
```

I would like to push the `:id` parameter programmatically as

```
import routes from '../../constants/routes.js'
const UserListItem = ({name, id, history}) => (
  <li onClick={ () => history.push(routes.user_details, {id}) }>
  {name}
  </li>
)
```

The internet seems to be filled with `<Redirect to={/user/${id}/details} />` which doesn't seem optimal as I would like to reuse my constant route

Comment: `routes.user_details.replace(':id', id)`?

Comment: right but that would bypass any rules <Router> has in place. I was hoping react-router had something in place for this

Comment: what? it wouldn't bypass any rules. what do you mean?

Comment: that's a one off solution, I'd have to replace for every route I build and it would not support `/user/:id/messages/:status(active|inactive)` for example. as I mentioned I was hoping react-router provided a utility for this.

Answer (score 1):

depends on how you are using these route constants I guess. An I'm not sure what you mean by "bypass any rules" either, but you could maybe change your constants to be functions.

```
export defaults {
  userDetails: (id = ":id") => `/user/${id}/details`,
}
```

usage:

```
path={routes.userDetails()} -> `/user/:id/details`

history.push(routes.userDetails("abc123")) -> `/user/abc123/details`
```

Comment: thanks, I was hoping react-router would provide this type of utility instead of me writing one.